# ClassNotFound Exception in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Actually I created the jar file from project containing the user define java file and I am trying to access the java file present in the jar using Servlet, but getting `ClassNotFound` exception.

As per the code given below I am accessing  `JcaTest` java file present in the jar:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {

    String k = request.getParameter("string");

    JcaTest ab = new JcaTest(null);


    String a = ab.newMethod(k);
    String b= ab.newMethod1(a);
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

I added the jar in web app folder also but it is not working .

Comment: You need to add jar in `web-INF/lib` folder

Comment: i added it in web-INF/lib folder but still getting the same exception

Comment: Did you see that jar file is in your class path ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the classes in your jar reference to other classes, which not in your WEB-INF/lib.

Put all necessary jars to WEB-INF/lib !